# Different python functions to fit cubic splines, finding coefficients

Tags: scipy, spline, smoothing, cubic-spline

I want to fit a cubic spline in Python to noisy x, y data and extract the spline coefficients for each interval (i.e. I would expect to obtain four spline coefficients for each interval)

So far, I have tried (all from scipy.interpolate):

1) CubicSpline, but this method does not allow me to smooth the spline, resulting in unrealistic, jumpy coefficient data.

2) Combining splrep and splev, e.g.

```
tck = splrep(x, y, k=3, s=1e25)
```

where I extract the coefficients/knots using

```
F = PPoly.from_spline(tck)
coeffs = F.c
knots = F.x
```

However, I cannot find smooth coefficients over the full x-range (jumps between values close to zero and 1e23, which is unphysical) even if I ramp up the smoothing parameter s to very large numbers that ultimately lead to too small numbers of knots since the number of knots decreases with s. It seems that I cannot find a suitable parameter s and number of knots at the same time.

3) I used 
    UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=3, s=0.03)
Here, I found a better sensitivity to changing s, but the corresponding get_coeffs() method does not provide 4 coefficients for each interval but only one, which I do not understand.

4) I also tried a piecewise ridged linear regression with a third order polynomial, but this method provides too large percentage errors for the fit, so it would be great to get one of the standard spline methods working.

What am I missing? Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 3):

The concrete issue I see here is that `UnivariateSpline` does not yield the algebraic coefficients of various powers of x in the interpolating spline. This is because the coefficients it keeps in the private `_data` property, which it also returns with `get_coeffs` method, are a kind of [B-spline coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline). These coefficients describe the spline without any redundancy (you need N of them for a spline with N degrees of freedom), but the basis splines that they are attached to are somewhat complicated.

But you can get the kind of coefficients you want by using the `derivatives` method of the spline object. It returns all four derivatives at a given point x, from which the [Taylor coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) at that point are easy to find. It is natural to use this method with x being the knots of interpolation, excluding the rightmost one; the coefficients obtained are valid from that knot to the next one. Here is an example, complete with "fancy" formatted output.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
spl = UnivariateSpline(np.arange(6), np.array([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]), s=0)
kn = spl.get_knots()
for i in range(len(kn)-1):
    cf = [1, 1, 1/2, 1/6] * spl.derivatives(kn[i])
    print("For {0} <= x <= {1}, p(x) = {5}*(x-{0})^3 + {4}*(x-{0})^2 + {3}*(x-{0}) + {2}".format(kn[i], kn[i+1], *cf))
```

The knots are 0, 2, 3, 5 in this example. The output  is:

```
For 0.0 <= x <= 2.0, p(x) = -3.1222222222222222*(x-0.0)^3 + 11.866666666666667*(x-0.0)^2 + -10.744444444444445*(x-0.0) + 3.000000000000001
For 2.0 <= x <= 3.0, p(x) = 4.611111111111111*(x-2.0)^3 + -6.866666666666667*(x-2.0)^2 + -0.7444444444444436*(x-2.0) + 4.000000000000001
For 3.0 <= x <= 5.0, p(x) = -2.322222222222221*(x-3.0)^3 + 6.966666666666665*(x-3.0)^2 + -0.6444444444444457*(x-3.0) + 1.0000000000000016
```

Note that for each piece, `cf` holds the coefficients starting with the lowest degree, so the order is reversed when formatting the string.

(Of course, you'd probably want to do something else with these coefficients)

To check that the formulas are correct, I copy-pasted them for plotting:

[image: spline]